# AppStore transfer - app identifier changed

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I created new Developer account then I transferred an application to the new account. Then I created the same identifier under the new account. And  build App and upload to AppStore.

```
I have got the warning with WARNING ITMS-9000: "Potential Loss of Keychain Access.
The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['OLD_TEAM_ID.com.(my-app-id)'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['NEW_TEAM_ID.com.(my-app-id). 
This will result in a loss of keychain access. For more information, please consult (url)".
```

This id prefix is ID of Development team. When I migrated App to the new account, this Development team id is changed.

But next problem is the sharing extension stops working. I think that is the same problem... Because I have got this error in Simulator

```
Service exited due to SIGILL
```

Is there some chance to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in app group identifier name. It must be the same as before. You must go to Developer portal -> identifiers (select App groups) and remove the group name from the original owner account. Then go the new developer account and create exactly the same group identifier.

Then it works!